# Templated function with variable number of params of certain templated type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

```
template <int S>
struct Vec {};
```

Now i want to write a function which will accept only these vectors, but with different values of template parameter. It could be called like this:

```
f(Vec<1>(), Vec<2>(), Vec<3>());
```

How can i write such a function? I would like to use parameter pack. Could it be something like:

```
template<int... Ss>
f(Vec<Ss...> vecs);
```

I would like to let user see that the function expects vectors just from its declaration rather from compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
template <int... Ss>
void f(Vec<Ss>... vecs) { ... }
```

A program that builds in my setup:

```
template <int S>
struct Vec {};

template <int... Ss>
void f(Vec<Ss>... vecs)
{
}

int main()
{
   f(Vec<1>(), Vec<2>(), Vec<3>());
}
```